# Incorrect Decimal value c# .Net

Tags: c#, decimal, decimalformat

I have a WebSocket which gives me the below data:

```
"t:1_26000,ltp:16201.8,ltq:0,tb:0,ts:0,v:0,ap:16201.8,ltt:1339354680,lut:1339354680,pc:-1.68,o:16283.95,h:16324.7,l:16172.6,c:16201.8,bt:1,mt:1,ai:0|0|0|0,bi:0|0|0|0"
```

*(The leading and trailing `"` are part of the data.)*

Problem: sometimes I get the value as `162018` or `165.018` instead of `16201.8`.

I use the below code to get the value:

```
string Datainfo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
string[] d = Datainfo.Split(',');
var dd = d.Where(x => x.Contains("ltp")).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
decimal LTP = Convert.ToDecimal(dd.Split(':').LastOrDefault());
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Start with twitching `Convert.ToDecimal()` to `Decimal.Parse()`. Second, start logging the raw string and parsed decimal values somewhere, so you can compare the difference. Third, if you have JSON data, **LOOK UP THE JSON PROPERTY** instead of splitting up the string!

Comment: dd can also be null ;)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Didn't get your last point  LOOK UP THE JSON PROPERTY instead of splitting up the string.
Can u tell me more about that?

Comment: @DimiTakis Exception is handled there no chance of null value 

It's in Try Catch already.

Comment: You have some `data`. You are converting this data to a JSON string, and then doing a bunch of manipulation to the string to find the LTP value. Something in that `data` will **already have the LTP value you want**. It will be much less work and much less error prone to look inside the `data` variable directly.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn

I have below value in 'data'

t:1_26000,ltp:16201.8,ltq:0,tb:0,ts:0,v:0,ap:16201.8,ltt:1339354680,lut:1339354680,pc:-1.68,o:16283.95,h:16324.7,l:16172.6,c:16201.8,bt:1,mt:1,ai:0|0|0|0,bi:0|0|0|0

Can u give me a sample of how i can get ltp data?

Comment: Note: `Select(x => x)` does nothing, you can remove that.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Any luck to get help from you ..?
i am getting below value in `data` 

t:1_26000,ltp:16201.8,ltq:0,tb:0,ts:0,v:0,ap:16201.8,ltt:1339354680,lut:1339354680,pc:-1.68,o:16283.95,h:16324.7,l:16172.6,c:16201.8,bt:1,mt:1,ai:0|0|0|0,bi:0|0|0|0

Comment: What datatype us the 'data' variable? And if you say 'string' I'm done.